# Bordering div that contain added elements by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to make a border that surround all the elements, and this div should have a stander height and width in the first and if the element reached the length of it it should expands according to the number of the elements.

```
<div id="contText" ></div>

<input id="send" type="button" value="Send" onclick="myFunction()"></input>
```

### CSS

```
         div#contText {

text-align: center;
top:30px;
width:400px;
height:300px;
background-color:white;
border:1px solid black;
        }
```

### Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
  var para = document.createElement("P");
  var t = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph.");
  para.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("contText").appendChild(para);
}
```

Comment: Well since you declare the height you will have to change the height at some point. i would rather use min-height. To let the div expend. And add overflow : hidden to it so it will always ajust to the content.

Comment: I rather use `overflow:auto; ` so it will scroll with the user , but is there anyway to make the scrollbar be always in the bottom ? @MadeInDreams

Comment: overflow-y:scroll;    or x will make the scrollbar always visible

Comment: Thanks @MadeInDreams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `min-height` (and `min-width`) to have the height initially set to `300px` and then expand as the content in the `div` increases

```js
function myFunction() {
  var para = document.createElement("P");
  var t = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph.");
  para.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("contText").appendChild(para);
}
```

```css
div#contText {

  text-align: center;
  top:30px;
  min-width:400px;
  min-height:300px;
  background-color:white;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="contText" ></div>

<input id="send" type="button" value="Send" onclick="myFunction()"></input>
```

if you want a scroll bar to always show use `overflow-y: scroll`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var para = document.createElement("P");
  var t = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph.");
  para.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("contText").appendChild(para);
}
```

```css
div#contText {

  text-align: center;
  top:30px;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:white;
  border:1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="contText" ></div>

<input id="send" type="button" value="Send" onclick="myFunction()"></input>
```